# Python post-processing

Tags: python, post-processing

i have to analyse/visualize results of simulations(Simulink, EES) in Python.

Averaged I have to import 40-100 variables (each variable is a vector with several thausend rows) from a result file: Each Variable has a appropriate path in result.data("path to varaible")
My workflow is the following (not really efficient):

```
Result = {}
Result["VariableA"] = result.data("moment1.p3.Temperatur")
Result["VariableB"] = result.data("moment2.p1.pressure")
..
..
```

At the end I have a code with around 100 lines - and every line is almost the same. So I assume that there is maybe a better way to do that.

I would be very grateful for suggestions

Comment: possibly relevant for you: https://github.com/kdavies4/ModelicaRes#see-also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a dictionary with all the variable/path definitions like

```
paths = {"VariableA": "moment1.p3.Temperatur",
         "VariableB": "moment2.p1.pressure",
         ...
        }
```

Then you can do

```
Result = {key: result.data(paths[key]) for key in paths}
```

or (possibly faster)

```
Result = {key: result.data(value) for key, value in paths.items()}
```

(assuming Python 3, otherwise use `paths.iteritems()`)